# Copy constructor c++ weird behavoir?

Tags: c++, deep-copy, shallow-copy

Hi I have a class which includes an array, I'm not passing this through my class constuctor (could be going wrong here?) The array is just defined in the class then initialized in a read method.

But in the main I make an instance of the class like:

```
myClass myClass1;
```

Then do:

```
myClass1 = myClass2;
```

Now I use a bubble sort method on the first class instance like:

```
MyClass1.sort();
```

Now when I write both of these instances out to text after the sort they are both sorted?

I have had a read into shallow and deep copys, but I can't understand why a method called after the shallow copy, would result in both of them being sorted? Is this expected behavoir?

a little more information:

In my class I just define the array as:

```
static string myArray[5];
```

then in a write method I write the 5 elements to it, is there a better way of doing this, I have to use a method to intialize it though.

Comment: *Are you sure there is an array involved*? Are you not [confusing arrays with pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/46642)? It would help if you could post a small example that demonstrates this behaviour.

Comment: give me more code. How do I know you didn't mess up somewhere else?

Comment: I'll update my post with a little more code but I dont want to post too much as its for an assignment I just want to get my head around why this is happening! Although I know that means I have to post more code!

Comment: That code is irrelevant. Post us the class definition.

Comment: If you declare something as `static`, it is shared between *all* instances of the class.

Comment: “is there a better way of doing this”—yes, use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of a C array.  The class templates in the standard library provide more functionality and are more type safe (e.g., they don't decay to pointers implicitly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my class I just define the array as:
>
> ```
> static string myArray[5];
> ```
>
> Should I declare it in the header, as its only declared in the cpp file? As its still copying both.

If you declare that *outside* of a class definition it will be a global variable. *There will only be one instance of it*. You need to declare it inside the class, and *not* `static`:

```
class MyClass1 {
    // other things...
    string myArray[5];
};
```

In any case, this kind of basic question is better answered by consulting [a good C++ introductory book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Should I declare it in the header, as its only declared in the cpp file? As its still copying both.

Comment: What? You should declare it *inside* the class!

Answer (score 3):

How is your array defined/created? If you create it with `new` and reference it with a pointer, you'll need a custom copy constructor creating a deep copy (i.e. creating a new instance of the array and copying its contents). The default copy constructor will only do a shallow copy, so both instances would use the same memory (i.e. both pointers' point to the same array on the heap).

This will work with the default copy constructor:

```
class myclass {
    char text[256];
}
```

This won't work with the default copy constructor (at least not as expected):

```
class myclass {
    char *text;
    myclass() : text(new char[256]) {}
    ~myclass() { delete [] text; }
}
```

A member defined as `static` will never be copied. All instances share it without further code required:

```
class myclass {
    static char text[256];
}
```

A copy constructor for the second case could look like this (note this is simplified and not checking for valid values and such):

```
myclass(const myclass &base) : text(new char[256]) { strcpy(text, base.text); }
```

General rule of thumb:
Do I use any pointer member that is assigned the return value of some `new`? If so, write a copy constructor. If not, hen use he default one (unless you've got other reasons).

Comment: My array is defined like so: static string myArray[5];

Comment: A static member is shared between all instances of the class. If you want each instance to have its own copy, remove the `static` keyword.